# BigQuery Date Functions Not Found in API Querying

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I am getting a ApiError: Function not found: STRFTIME_UTC_USEC error when I try to run the following query using the node.js BQ API:

```
SELECT STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(created, "%h %d %Y") as user_created from `tablePath`
```

According to the BQ docs 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#datetimefunctions , the Function STRFTIME_UTC_USEC is available in BQ. and in fact the same query works in the Query builder on the BQ Console Website (just change the table escape characters from `` to []).

The code calling the query looks like:

```
const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const sqlQuery = SELECT STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(created, "%h %d %Y") as user_created from `tablePath`
const options = {
query: sqlQuery,
useLegacySql: false // Use standard SQL syntax for queries.
};
bigquery.query(options)    
.then(function (results) {
  const rows = results[0];
  console.log(rows);
  callback(rows); 
});
```

Any solutions out there for formatting timestamps with node.js API for BigQuery? I also get the same error trying to use the YEAR() function in the query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this function is supported by Legacy SQL, not by Standard SQL, but below makes it use standard sql thus conflict/error

```
useLegacySql: false // Use standard SQL syntax for queries.
```

Just remove this or change it to true

In case if you need/want to be in Standard SQL - use below as an example

```
SELECT 
  FORMAT_DATE("%h %d %Y", CURRENT_DATE()), 
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%h %d %Y", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `STRFTIME_UTC_USEC`, which is specific to legacy SQL, use the [`FORMAT_TIMESTAMP`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#format_timestamp) function. See also the [migration guide from legacy to standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).